# how to access and modify google workspace domain user's google drive files as a domain administrator using google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

Objective:

as a google workspace domain admin for a school that uses google workspace education, I want to create a google apps script that given a google workspace user's email address (the current owner), the scritp should be able to get a list of all the user's folders and files in their google drive and then it should also be able to transfer the ownership of those folders and files to domain user and add the current owner as a viewer so they can only see the folders/files but can't modify them in any way.

things I tried:

- DriveApp can access files/folders and change the ownership of the file/folder but only if you are the owner, and I want to do this as the domain admin, regardless which user owns the google drive and respective files/folders.
- Drive API, seems to do the same as DriveApp as far you're the owner, I couldn't figure out how to give Drive API admin permissions so I can see every domain user google drive file list, if that's even possible.
- GAM advance: I found this as management tool, I set it and it migh do what I need but it's bit complex for me, plus I was really hoping to be able to build the tool myself.

What worked halfway:

I found this: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2#using-service-accounts which refers to using a service account. It took a while but I manage to get a list of items that exist on a user's google drive with the script below. but I can't figure out how to access those files/folders so I can change the ownership or set viewers on them. I think I read that the service account will only give me read-only access so I'm doubting this is even possible.

Here's what I got so far:

```
function main(){
  // Private key and client email of the service account.
  var key = getJsonKey()    
  var clientEmail = 'service_account_email_setup_in_google_dev_console';
  // Email address of the user to impersonate.
  var userEmail = 'a_regular_domain_user@my_google_workspace_domain.com';
  
  try{
    var drive = getDriveService_(key,userEmail,clientEmail);
    if (drive.hasAccess()) {
      // this code gets me a json response with items that list id's and urls and other 
      //file metadata of the
      // files that belongs to the domain user, this is as far as i got.
      var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
         headers: {
           Authorization: 'Bearer ' + drive.getAccessToken()
         }
       });
       var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
       //the following code returns a fileid in the user's google 
       //drive not shared with the admin
       var fileid = JSON.stringify(result.items[0].id) 
       Logger.log(fileid);
       //but the following code returns an error indicating that the 
       //file is not found (in reality it's not accessible by the 
       //admin account)
       var file = Drive.Files.get(fileid);
       
       //access a list of items and as I traverse it I'd like to 
       //change the ownership and 
       //add the the current user as a file viewer
       //??
 
    } else {
      Logger.log(drive.getLastError());
    }
  }catch (e){
    Logger.log(e)
  }
}

// Load the JSON key file with private key for service account
function getJsonKey(){
  var keyFile = DriveApp.getFileById("json_fileid_in_drive_obtained_from_googledevcons");
  var key = JSON.parse(keyFile.getBlob().getDataAsString()).private_key;
  return key 
}

function reset() {
  getDriveService__().reset();
}

//get the google drive from the domain user's email address
function getDriveService_(key,userEmail,clientEmail) {
  return OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:' + userEmail)
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
      .setPrivateKey(key)
      .setIssuer(clientEmail)
      .setSubject(userEmail)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction, the only part you are missing currently is setting up [`Domain Wide Delegation`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python) this will allow you to impersonate the users in your domain so you can make the changes on behalf of them by granting the service account permissions through the above mentioned DWD.

Since you have already created the `Oauth2Service` you will just need to send the user to impersonate through the `OauthParams`:

```
const oauthParams = {
    serviceName: 'Nameofyourservice',
    serviceAccount,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://mail.google.com', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam'],
    userToImpersonate: 'usertoimpersonate@test.com',
  };
```

The scopes were from the `Marketplace API` as an example.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel. 
1. DWD had already been set in Security>API Controls >Domain-wide Delegation for 2 scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  and .../drive.file

Comment: 2. the code above works in the sense that I can get file ids that belong to the userEmail (the account I'm trying to impersonate).

Comment: 3. what I'm unsure how to do is something like
var file = DriveApp.getFilebyId(<..file id that belongs to userEmail...>) or
var file = Drive.Files.get(<..file id that belongs to userEmail...>);
file.setOwner(<...adminEmail@mydomain.com..>
I though I could do it with the service returned by getDriveService_() but that's the part I have no clue how to do and I can't find examples. If I use the id from the response it just tells me that the file is not found, becuase my user has not been shared on it, I don't want that, hence the need to be able to impersionate.